# Rules/guidelines for documenting C# code?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, documentation

I am a relatively new developer and have been assigned the task of documenting code written by an advanced C# developer. My boss told me to look through it, and to document it so that it would be easier to modify and update as needed.

My question is: Is there a standard type of Documentation/Comment structure I should follow? My boss made it sound like everyone knew exactly how to document the code to a certain standard so that anyone could understand it.

I am also curious if anyone has a good method for figuring out unfamiliar code or function uncertainty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, you really got the short straw here... :-P

Comment: Microsoft has a [documentation guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which would be good to follow.  Then there of course is the framework itself.  Look at how they've documented everything for the classes, members and whatnot and use that as a model.  Otherwise, this would be a fairly subjective topic.

Comment: @Noldorin: Well not necessarily. You can really learn a lot from looking through another persons code and commenting it.

Comment: @tkeE2036: You can learn even more by writing your own.

Comment: This is awful job. The fact that the code is not already commented/documented is a huge warning sign. The fact that your boss is not providing specifications for how he wants the code commented/documented and acting like there is one and only one way to comment/document code is a huge warning sign.

Comment: @Jason: Yeah I agree with you (on both comments). Also why is the developer who wrote this not tasked with documenting her own code?

Comment: Was the code really written by an "advanced C# **program**" or programmer?

Comment: Yes good comments. If you don't have a standard at work you should document the steps and set the bar so the next programmer can write their own comments.

Comment: @Jason, I couldn't agree more. Having to rectify a supposedly "advanced C# programmer's" utter lack of comments without any guidelines is not only futile but misguided. If one wants to learn, go comment/document *one's own* code *as one writes it*.

Comment: @aquinas: I presumed it was a sentient machine. Programs programming other programs. Matrix shit, you know. :-)

Comment: @tkeE2036: The other developer is a contractor and I am guessing makes a lot more and I think believes he is to good for comments. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard seems to be [XML Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (MSDN Technet article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx)).

You can use `///` at the beginning of each line of documentation comments. There are standard XML style elements for documenting your code; each should follow the standard `<element>Content</element>` usage. Here are some of the elements:

```
<c>               Used to differentiate code font from normal text 
                    <c>class Foo</c>
<code>
<example>
<exception>
<para>            Used to control formatting of documentation output. 
                    <para>The <c>Foo</c> class...</para>
<param>
<paramref>        Used to refer to a previously described <param>  
                    If <paramref name="myFoo" /> is <c>null</c> the method will...
<remarks>
<returns>
<see>             Creates a cross-ref to another topic. 
                     The <see cref="System.String" /><paramref name="someString"/>
                     represents...

<summary>         A description (summary) of the code you're documenting.
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you really did end up getting the short straw.

Unfortunately I think you've stumbled on one of the more controversial subjects of software development in general. Comments can be seen as extremely helpful where necessary, and unnecessary cruft when used wrongly. You'll have to be careful and decide quite carefully what goes where.

As far as commenting practice, it's usually down to the corporation or the developer. A few common rules I like to use are:

- Comment logic that isn't clear (and consider a refactor)
- Only Xml-Doc methods / properties that could be questioned (or, if you need to give a more detailed overview)
- If your comments exceed the length of the containing method / class, you might want to think about comment verbosity, or even consider a refactor.
- Try and imagine a new developer coming across this code. What questions would they ask?

It sounds like your boss is referring to commenting logic (most probably so that you can start understanding it) and using xml-doc comments.

If you haven't used xml-doc comments before, check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which should give you a little guidance on use and where appropriate.

If your workloadi s looking a little heavy (ie, lots of code to comment), I have some good news for you - there's an excellent plugin for Visual Studio that may help you out for xml-doc comments. **[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)** can make xml-doc commenting methods / classes etc much easier (but remember to change the default placeholder text it inserts in there!)

Remember, you may want to check with your boss on just what parts of the code he wants documented before you go on a ghostdoc spree.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a worry that the original programmer didn't bother to do one of the most important parts of his job. However, there are lots of terrible "good" programmers out there, so this isn't really all that unusual.

However, getting you to document the code is also a pretty good training mechanism - you have to read and understand the code before you can write down what it does, and as well as gaining knowledge of the systems, you will undoubtedly pick up a few tips and tricks from the good (and bad!) things the other programmer has done.

To help get your documentation done quickly and consistently, you might like to try my add-in for Visual Studio, [AtomineerUtils Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/). This will help with the boring grunt work of creating and updating the comments, make sure the comments are fully formed and in sync with the code, and let you concentrate on the code itself.

As to working out how the code works...

Hopefully the class, method, parameter and variable names will be descriptive. This should give you a pretty good starting point. You can then take one method or class at a time and determine if you believe that the code within it delivers what you think the naming implies. If there are unit tests then these will give a good indication of what the programmer expected the code to do (or handle). Regardless, try to write some (more) unit tests for the code, because thinking of special cases that might break the code, and working out why the code fails some of your tests, will give you a good understanding of what it does and how it does it. Then you can augment the basic documentation you've written with the more useful details (can this parameter be null? what range of values is legal? What will the return value be if you pass in a blank string? etc)

This can be daunting, but if you start with the little classes and methods first (e.g. that Name property that just returns a name string) you will gain familiarity with the surrounding code and be able to gradually work your way up to the more complex classes and methods.

Once you have basic code documentation written for the classes, you should then be in a position to write external overview documentation that describes how the system as a whole functions. And then you'll be ready to work on that part of the codebase because you'll understand how it all fits together.

I'd recommend using XML documentation (see the other answers) as this is immediately picked up by Visual Studio and used for intellisense help. Then anyone writing code that calls your classes will get help in tooltips as they type the code. This is such a major bonus when working with a team or a large codebase, but many companies/programmers just don't realise what they've been missing, banging their (undocumented) rocks together in the dark ages :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your boss is referring to the following XML Documentation Comments.

[XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Warning: This is *not* real, viable, commerical documentation, this is a quick-and-dirty hack that tells you the meaning of code constructs

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth asking your boss if he has any examples of code that is already documented so you can see first-hand what he is after.

Mark Needham has written a few blog posts about reading/documenting code (see [Archive for the ‘Reading Code’ Category](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/category/reading-code/).

I remember reading [Reading Code: Rhino Mocks](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/28/reading-code-rhino-mocks/) some time ago that talks about diagramming the code to help keep track of where you are and to 'map out' what's going on.

Hope that helps - good luck!